# Не работает Animate.css

Tags: html, css, animate

Делаю все, как надо : Скачал файл, подключил, ввел в классе элемента "animated fadeInLeft", но анимация не работает, при чем ни одна из анимаций не работают. У меня даже на сайте Animate.css не работает ни одна анимация. В чем причина ?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <title>Tinyone</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-5 ml-auto ">
            <nav>
              <ul class="menu d-flex justify-content-center">
                <li class="menu__item">
                  <a href="#">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu__item">
                  <a href="#">Support</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu__item">
                  <a href="#">Blog</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="offer">
              <h1 class="offer__title">
                Inspire your inspiration
              </h1>
              <div class="offer__intro">
                Simple to use for your app, products <br> showcase and your inspiration
              </div>
              <p class="offer__text animated fadeInLeft">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vitae eros eget tellus tristique bibendum. Donec rutrum sed sem quis venenatis. Proin viverra risus a eros volutpat tempor. In quis arcu et eros porta lobortis sit 
              </p>
              <ul class="icons d-flex">
                <li class="icons__item">
                  <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="icons__item">
                  <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-android"></i></a>  
                </li>
                <li class="icons__item">
                  <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-windows"></i></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: откуда мы знаем? может вы криво подключили, может вы не так что-то написали, может файл вообще пустой, может у вас ошибка где-то

Comment: @meine Добавил код

Comment: animate.css точно подключается на страницу? посмотрите в консоли на наличие ошибок. В сниппете, что вы привели у элемента .animate.fadeInLeft нет никаких стилей для анимации, поэтому в данном случае анимации нет

Comment: @Famous, у Вас при входе на сайт не показывается такое сообщение? Скриншот: https://take.ms/W3yj8

Comment: @hisbvdis да, есть такое сообщение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я разобрался, в чем была проблема -  я отключил анимацию у себя на компьютере. Чтобы решить данную проблему, нужно : *Мой Компьютер > ПКМ > Свойства > Дополнительные параметры системы > Быстродействие > Параметры >Поставить галочку "Анимированные элементы управления и элементы внутри окна".*